# How do i remove all the excess white space from an non-displayed image on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Currently, I am using an image as my css-background, however I am using clip path so that only the top left corner of the image is shown as the background. This causes the other hidden parts of the image to be shown as white space on my webpage (making my webpage very long and wide). I have played around with the margins but I can't seem to get rid of all that extra space.

Any ideas?

Thanks

HTML

```
<div id="image">  
<canvas id="myCanvas" width = "500" height= "500"> </canvas>
</div>

<div>
    The extra space from the image is pushing this line to the bottom creating extra space in between
</div>
```

CSS

```
canvas {     
    background-image: url("http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 300px 300px 0);
  -moz-clip-path: inset(0 300px 300px 0);
  -o-clip-path: inset(0 300px 300px 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 300px 300px 0);

}
```

Please see fiddle for an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rqrvqLvv/

Comment: You should attach a sample, it's very difficult to help without some form of presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to fix it.

## 1. I don't care about backwards-compatibility

This one's pretty simple.

Ditch the container `.image` and just include the following CSS as part of your `canvas` rule:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: -1;
```

## <kbd>[JSFiddle Example #1](https://jsfiddle.net/rqrvqLvv/2/)</kbd>

## 2. I do care about backwards-compatibility

Ditch the container `.image` and just include the following CSS as part of your `canvas` rule:

```
position: absolute!important;
z-index: 0!important;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

and add this rule:

```
body > * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

## <kbd>[JSFiddle Example #2](https://jsfiddle.net/rqrvqLvv/3/)</kbd>

Comment: How do i get rid of all the extra space underneath and on the right side of the image so that the scroll bar isnt present?